# Modals + Not + Past Participles

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we use Models + not + Past Participles while constructing English sentences?

E.g.

a) This pizza would be the best ever if it *would not arrived* cold.

b) Custom drapery *should not arrived* damaged, dirty and have dead bugs stuck on fabric.

c) Realization that the product *might not arrived* by the time of his friend wedding; Still buy it because the user needed it;

d) Cubans approved in one fiscal year *may not arrived* in the United States until the following year.

e) The police were outside the house, but *would not arrived* quick enough to stop Bonnie from killing Ken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal verbs cannot be matched with a participle.

They must be followed by a short infinitive (which can be another auxiliary verb in a longer structure).

E.g.:

> to go: I should **go** back to work.
>
> to have (auxiliary): I should **have** said nothing. (note that "said" is a participle)

Comment: You mean all my examples are incorrect.

Comment: pretty much yes, according to my understanding. I never encountered constructs similar to what you presented in your examples.